# AMQ224011: Cannot find queue messages

Tags: activemq-artemis

I am using Artemis 2.21.0 version and storing the messages in PostgreSQL DB. Recently we have started getting following errors.

Any idea what can be the reason of the error?

```
11:17:09.638 [http-nio-8080-exec-24] ERROR org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server - AMQ224011: Cannot find queue messages 3 for message 191,140,297,440 while processing scheduled messages
11:17:09.638 [http-nio-8080-exec-24] ERROR org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server - AMQ224011: Cannot find queue messages 3 for message 191,140,297,441 while processing scheduled messages
11:17:09.638 [http-nio-8080-exec-24] ERROR org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server - AMQ224011: Cannot find queue messages 3 for message 191,140,297,441 while processing scheduled messages
11:17:09.638 [http-nio-8080-exec-24] ERROR org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server - AMQ224011: Cannot find queue messages 3 for message 191,140,297,445 while processing scheduled messages
```

This is what I have in my `broker.xml`:

```xml
<address-settings>
    <address-setting match="#">
        <max-delivery-attempts>2</max-delivery-attempts>
        <redelivery-delay>1000</redelivery-delay>
        <max-size-bytes>104857600</max-size-bytes>
        <page-size-bytes>10485760</page-size-bytes>
        <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
    </address-setting>
    <address-setting match="dataQueue1">
        <dead-letter-address>deadLetterQueue1</dead-letter-address>
        <expiry-delay>604800000</expiry-delay> <!-- one week -->
    </address-setting>
    <address-setting match="dataQueue2">
        <dead-letter-address>deadLetterQueue2</dead-letter-address>
        <expiry-delay>604800000</expiry-delay> <!-- one week -->
    </address-setting>
</address-settings>
```

There is no explicit setting for `global-max-size` so its taking half of heap size as default, i.e.:

```
AMQ221057: Global Max Size is being adjusted to 1/2 of the JVM max size (-Xmx). being defined as 8,564,768,768
```

On JMS server startup following error logged

```
[WARN ] 2023-05-12 18:58:34.708 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] server - AMQ222010: Critical IO Error, shutting down the server. file=org.apache.activemq.artemis.jdbc.store.file.JDBCSequentialFile@15560d14, message=Error attempting to open JDBC file.
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: permission denied for large object 1635180
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveFastpathResult(QueryExecutorImpl.java:766) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.fastpathCall(QueryExecutorImpl.java:558) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.fastpath.Fastpath.fastpath(Fastpath.java:105) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.fastpath.Fastpath.fastpath(Fastpath.java:146) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.fastpath.Fastpath.getInteger(Fastpath.java:158) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.largeobject.LargeObject.<init>(LargeObject.java:102) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.largeobject.LargeObjectManager.open(LargeObjectManager.java:257) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.largeobject.LargeObjectManager.open(LargeObjectManager.java:240) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jdbc.store.file.PostgresLargeObjectManager.open(PostgresLargeObjectManager.java:83) ~[artemis-jdbc-store-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jdbc.store.file.PostgresSequentialSequentialFileDriver.getPostGresLargeObjectSize(PostgresSequentialSequentialFileDriver.java:186) ~[artemis-jdbc-store-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jdbc.store.file.PostgresSequentialSequentialFileDriver.loadFile(PostgresSequentialSequentialFileDriver.java:92) ~[artemis-jdbc-store-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jdbc.store.file.JDBCSequentialFileFactoryDriver.openFile(JDBCSequentialFileFactoryDriver.java:112) ~[artemis-jdbc-store-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jdbc.store.file.JDBCSequentialFile.load(JDBCSequentialFile.java:110) ~[artemis-jdbc-store-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jdbc.store.file.JDBCSequentialFile.open(JDBCSequentialFile.java:104) ~[artemis-jdbc-store-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.paging.impl.PagingStoreFactoryDatabase.reloadStores(PagingStoreFactoryDatabase.java:220) ~[artemis-server-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.paging.impl.PagingManagerImpl.reloadStores(PagingManagerImpl.java:352) ~[artemis-server-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.paging.impl.PagingManagerImpl.start(PagingManagerImpl.java:456) ~[artemis-server-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.initialisePart1(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:3196) ~[artemis-server-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.LiveOnlyActivation.run(LiveOnlyActivation.java:68) ~[artemis-server-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.internalStart(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:663) ~[artemis-server-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.start(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:571) ~[artemis-server-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
```

But `ActiveMQServerImpl.start` call does not throw any error

```
[INFO ] 2023-05-12 18:58:40.661 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] server - AMQ221034: Waiting 60000 milliseconds to obtain live lock
[INFO ] 2023-05-12 18:58:40.661 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] server - AMQ221035: Live Server Obtained live lock
[INFO ] 2023-05-12 18:58:49.259 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] load - activationComplete called
[INFO ] 2023-05-12 18:58:49.259 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] server - AMQ221007: Server is now live
```

Subsequent call to create SessionFactory throws the error

```
javax.jms.JMSRuntimeException: Failed to create session factory
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.JmsExceptionUtils.convertToRuntimeException(JmsExceptionUtils.java:88) ~[artemis-jms-client-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createContext(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:311) ~[artemis-jms-client-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createContext(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:299) ~[artemis-jms-client-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createContext(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:289) ~[artemis-jms-client-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
```

Comment: @JustinBertram Thanks for quick reply. I have updated the question with the Class Histogram

Comment: Heapsize is 16GB. 
Broker config is as follows: <max-size-bytes>104857600</max-size-bytes><page-size-bytes>10485760</page-size-bytes><address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I was debugging the issue at my end. Added more information in the original question under "Edit 2".
No explicit setting of global-max-size so its taking half of heap size as default. 
"AMQ221057: Global Max Size is being adjusted to 1/2 of the JVM max size (-Xmx). being defined as 8,564,768,768"

Comment: Address setting is added in the question

Comment: Is that histogram enumerating the top heap consumers? If so, I don't understand how you could get an `OutOfMemoryError` with a 16G heap and the top consumer (i.e. `byte[]`) is only using around 62MB of heap and the top consumer from Artemis is only using around 46MB. Can you share any more data from your heap analysis? This isn't making sense.

Comment: How are you starting the server? Are you manually invoking `ActiveMQServerImpl.start` somehow? Are you embedding the broker?

Comment: Yes, its an embedded broker. And I am manually invoking `ActiveMQServerImpl.start`. 
Basically calling `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.embedded.EmbeddedActiveMQ#initStart` first, setting postgres datasource and then calling `ActiveMQServerImpl.start`. Instead of just calling `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.embedded.EmbeddedActiveMQ#start` above steps are done as datasource is managed outside and did not want to duplicate its declaration.

Comment: In respect to Heap dump analysis - The above histogram is based on the heap dump taken randomly and is not conveying the correct information. Please ignore that for now. 
We could not take the Heap dump when `OutOfMemoryError` occurred. 

Now we have switched back to the File based persistence for the time being and since then no `OutOfMemoryError` occurred so somehow the error was related to Postgres based persistence.

Comment: We are trying to reproduce the same but as of now not sure what caused this error. From the error it looks like related to some permisson but will do more analysis. Also will share the Heap Dump analysis once I could reproduce this.

Comment: You need to add pertinent details _to your question_ so that folks don't need to read through the comments to get the whole picture. If the heap dump information is invalid please remove it from your question. You might consider using `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` to capture a heap dump when you hit an `OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: Removed the `OutOfMemoryError` reference from the question and -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError is already added now.